# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I try to test onclick behavior for this component but it is don't see the component why ?
I try to test this element and the test was pass but the behavior tell me it's undefined why?
this is my problem :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'click')

The Component need to test:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  welcome_page: {
    background:
      "linear-gradient( to right, white 0%, white 50%, black 50%,black 100%)",
  },

  text: {
    color: "white",
    whiteSpace : "nowrap",
    fontSize: "5rem",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    cursor: "pointer",
    "&::before": {
      content: "attr(data-heading)",
      position: "absolute",
      left: "0",
      color: "black",
      width: "50%",
      overflow: "hidden",
    },
  },
}));

export const Welcome = () => {
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  return (
    <Box height="calc(100vh - 65px)" className={classes.welcome_page}>
      <Typography
        className={classes.text}
        data-heading="WELCOME"
        data-testid="welcome"
        onClick = {()=>{navigate("/login")}}
      >
        WELCOME
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

The test code:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import React from 'react'
import {Welcome} from "./../views/Welcome/Welcome"
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import userEvent from '@testing-library/react'

describe("Welcome Component" , () => {

    test("Text Component" , () => {
        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Welcome />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    const welocmeElement = screen.getByTestId('welcome');
    expect(welocmeElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    } )

    test("Click handler to navigate" , () => {
        render(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Welcome />
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
        const history = createMemoryHistory();
        const welocmeElement = screen.getByTestId('welcome');
        userEvent.click(welocmeElement); // this is my problem
        expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual('/login');


    })

} )
```